# how to calculate height using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to calculate the height from the top to the point where i have added link.

How can i calculate height for example we use:

```
w = $(window).height();
```

to calculate the height of window.

Similarly i want to calculate the height of the anchor tag

```
<a href="#" id="calc"></a>
```

from the header to the point where that anchor is added?

```
outerh = $('#calc').outerHeight();
innerh = $('#calc').innerHeight();
```

I have tried above code but it return `18px` of height because it is calculating the height of that anchor tag.

Comment: offset().top is helpful to you.. but if you write some of your HTML code here then I can give accurate anser.!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate it using [`offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

> Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

Demo:

```js
console.log($('#calc').offset().top);
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;  
}

a {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="calc">link</a>
```

Comment: i am using following code to adjust my popup window acc. to the height  h = $('.calc').offset().top
    w = $(window).height();
  alert(h); alert(w);
  var cal=(w - h) /2;
  alert(cal); 
  
        $('.pop').css('margin-top', (w - h) /2 + "px");
 
the h = $('.calc').offset().top; height will vary as they are mentioned in the listing format.
how can i show the popup in the center

Answer (score 0):

Height from top for anchor tag from top edge of anchor tag

```
height_top= $('#calc').offset().top;
```

Height from top for anchor tag from bottom edge of anchor tag

```
height_top= $('#calc').offset().top + $('#calc').outerHeight();
```